# How to display response from ajax call inside DIV?

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I have a checkbox that updates a database table when checked/unchecked. The update is performed via an ajax call to a CFC. That part is working fine. Now I would like to display the response from the CFC inside a `div`.

The problem is my current code shows nothing and on the `console.log()` I get 'undefined'. How can I get the response from the cfc , ie `<cfset finalResult = {user_names=new_value_name}>` to display inside the div?

**jQuery/HTML**

```
<div id="content"></div>

<script>
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    var user_val = $('input[name=current_user]').val();
    alert(user_val);
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var checked = $(this).is(':checked');

    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ajaxcall.cfc?method=Getvalues',
            data: {
                checked: checked,
                mycheckbox: id,
                user_val: user_val
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var objData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                $('.mycheckbox').val(id);
                $('.user_val').val(user_val);
                //console.log(objData.user_names);
                $("#content").html(objData.user_names);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Error');
            },
            complete: function() {}
        });
    }
    });
    }

});    
</script>
```

**ajax_call.cfc**

```
<cfcomponent output="true">
   <cffunction name="Getvalues" access="remote" output="yes"  returntype="struct" returnformat="json">

       <cfset finalResult = {user_names=new_value_name}>
       <cfreturn finalResult>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Comment: That's XML, not JSON.

Comment: What's the point of doing `objData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`? That's the same as `objData = data`.

Comment: What is coming back from the Ajax call? What does the raw json look like. Also, should that be "innerHTML"? or am I confusing jQuery with regular JS?

Comment: @markAkruger i just solved the problem by doing it differently, should i close question?

Comment: Probably you should close it - but you should update with your fix or solution.

Answer (score -2):

You can parse Xml that you got via ajax request using `JQuery.parseXML()` method:

```
    var xml = "<cfcomponent output="true">
                <cffunction name="Getvalues" access="remote" output="yes"  
                returntype="struct" returnformat="json">
                <cfset finalResult = {user_names=new_value_name}>
                <cfreturn finalResult>
                </cffunction>
                </cfcomponent>",
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc ),
    $result = $xml.find( "cfset" ).attr('finalResult');
```

Comment: The "XML" in the code block is the source code for a 2nd file "ajax_call.cfc". Only a poorly configured web server would return that in the ajax call.